# change has_many to has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to convert models from has_many relation to has_one
here is my code

**models**

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :product_outline_attribute, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_outline_attribute

end

class ProductOutlineAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :activity

end
```

**controller**

```
class ActivitiesController < ProductOutlinesController

  def new
    @activity = Activity.new
    @activity.product_outline_attributes.new()
    render layout: false
  end

end
```

View

**new.html.haml**

```
.panel
  = form_for ([ @activity]), html: { class: 'ajax_form' } do |f|

    = render partial: 'product_outlines/form_activity_section', locals: { f: f }
```

**form_activity_section.html.haml**

```
= f.fields_for :product_outline_attribute do |ff_poa|
    = ff_poa.label :depth_of_knowledge
    = ff_poa.select :depth_of_knowledge, DEPTH_OF_KNOWLEDGE_LEVELS.map{ |k,v| [v,k] }, prompt: ( ff_poa.object.depth_of_knowledge.blank? ? 'Select Level' : nil )
```

earlier same code with has_many relation works because

@activity.product_outline_attributes.new returns an object

but with has_one

@activity.product_outline_attribute is nil

@activity.product_outline_attribute.new raises an exception

it makes sense after reading rails guide

Could someone help me on overcoming this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If activity has_one product_outline_attribute. You must new an instance by codes like this:

```
 @activity.build_product_outline_attribute
```